# Access current custom directive element inside link function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am manipulating DOM from the link function to add custom css using the directive attributes.

So here, first I will append one div with a class name, then find the div and add another div inside.

```
(function(){
   "use strict";

   var directive = function() {
      return {
         restrict: 'E',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // Configuration
            var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
            attrs.id = attrs.id || 'my-directive-'+id;
            element.attr('id', attrs.id);

            element.append('<h1>Here</h1>');

            element.append('<div class="my-directive-background">');
            element.find('.my-directive-background').css({'background-color':attrs.bColor});
            // add css 

            element.find('.my-directive-background').append('<div class="my-directive-foreground">');
            // add css
            element.find('.my-directive-foreground').css({'background-color':attrs.fColor});
         }
      };
   }

   var directives = angular.module("directives");
   directives.directive("myDirective",[directive]);

})();



<my-directive bColor="gray" fColor="red"  />
<my-directive bColor="gray" fColor="green" />
```

The problem is, when I use more than one same directive, the find method detects previous element also.

How to find only the div belongs to current directive element?

**Update: (Simple Solution)**

@Shripal's solution works fine. But the problem was because of the element closing syntax.
It's simply fixed when I changed

> `<my-directive bColor="gray" fColor="red" />`

to

> `<my-directive bColor="gray" fColor="red"></my-directive>`

Comment: Can't you just chain the appends? So the second append is done on the returned jQuery object of the first.

Comment: @Gustav I want to use css() also with each element, is it works?

Comment: Or create the jQuery-elements first(Background and foreground) and then add foreground to background and then add background to the element?

Comment: @Gustav I am not clear. Can you explain with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If jQuery is not added to your project, then find with class selector will not work.

I have created a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XmzhH7lGNlM1tnGpCka3?p=preview) using angular only with `element.children()`

Edit:

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XmzhH7lGNlM1tnGpCka3?p=preview) with jquery. I have optimized the code to first prepare the DOM and then appeded it to the element.

Comment: This one doesn't work for me. I have already included jquery. The actual problem is in the output I will get like this. ``<div class='background'><div class='foreground'></div><div class='foreground'></div></div>`` see the duplication. ``<div class='background'><div class='foreground'></div></div>``

Comment: I want to add the foreground only to the current element. When I run two directive, the second one adds foreground to first one also.

Comment: One more thing there will be some other elements like h1,p in the element before or after those divs.

Comment: Is your directive <my-directive><my-directive> closed properly, like <my-directive></my-directive><my-directive></my-directive>. Or it is a typo mistake?

Comment: No, there is no mistake. See in my code I am using class selector to add next div. thats why the second one adds to the first also. But how can I select only the current directives element?

Comment: I have update the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/XmzhH7lGNlM1tnGpCka3?p=preview. Is that the same output you want. And also do not use attribue in camel case instead use b-color and f-color.

Comment: What about other elements like header? http://plnkr.co/edit/fBWfSdkvS5zDE7TlO1Eh?p=preview

Comment: In your plunker you are not using jQuery. So element is an jqLite object.So you can use find with tag selector. I have forked your plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Ny5YLZbM7wxbLO8a2VTI?p=preview to append foreground element to only background div element.

Comment: In my real code I am using jquery, I f you want you can add here also. The main part is commented, after adding background and foreground I have to add custom css for each one. See in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68902/discussion-between-shripal-soni-and-devo).

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please include the actual code in this answer, as links may go down at any time.